# Compiling Objective-C app for Linux (API coverage)

Tags: objective-c, linux, macos, cocoa, gnustep

I might be asking something strange here, but I'm unsure where to begin. The thing is that I am considering writing a command line tool on a Mac using Obj-C and the Foundation classes.

But there is a very big risk that I would like to be able to compile it for different Linux distributions to run as a server app in the future.

I understand that it is not a problem in itself to compile Objective-C for Linux, but what I don't understand is the API coverage.

As I have understood it so far I can use GNUStep to compile for linux, but is there a good way for me to get an overview of the API coverage? What I mean is, if I use a class that has been added to the Foundation framework in OSX Lion lets say, how big is the risk of that not being available in GNUStep at that time?

I hope I am asking a question that you guys can understand, basically I want to avoid writing an app that can theoretically be compiled for linux, but not in practice because of missing classes etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An opinion: The risk is fairly high. GNU Step is an open source project and dependant on its volunteers to keep it up to date. OS X Lion has a small number of additions to Foundation and AppKit.

Your best option if you want it for *nix in the future will be to write it in generic C/C++ and then thinly wrap it in an `NSTask` if you want a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check if the API's you're using are available by consulting the [GNUStep base API docs](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/index.html).

You may want to target GNUStep as your base if compatibillity is a big concern. Compiling for mac should then be rather trivial, compared to moving the code the other way. Of course you always have the option of helping inplement whatever is missing from GNUStep too.