# Platform Independent Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking to build Objective C software components that can run on Mac OS X and Linux.  From my understanding, Cocoa software components can only be run on the Mac OS X platform. Does anyone have a good recommendation for a platform independent version of Objective C that can run on Mac OS X and Linux?

Comment: Yeah use C++, which is supported on all platforms.

Comment: While the question specifically refers to windows, many of the answers are generally cross-platform so you may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNUStep may be an option. Sources mentioned in the answer to this SO question:
[Compiling Objective-C app for Linux (API coverage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664855/compiling-objective-c-app-for-linux-api-coverage)